# Button click on android widget

Tags: android, widget

I have created a simple widget to rotate screen. when i clicked in the rotate button I could rotate it to lanscape but i couldn't rotate back to portrait.
where was my wrong ? this is my code

```
public class HelloWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {
public static String WIDGET_BUTTON = "android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE";

@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    RemoteViews remoteViews;
    remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.main);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context,HelloWidget.class);
    intent.setAction(WIDGET_BUTTON);
    PendingIntent actionPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,0,intent,0);
    remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btnRotate,actionPendingIntent);
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds,remoteViews);
}
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if(WIDGET_BUTTON.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        Display display = ((WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
        int Orientation = display.getRotation();
        if (Orientation == 0) {
            // rotate to lanscape
            Settings.System.putInt(context.getContentResolver(),
                    Settings.System.USER_ROTATION, 1);
        } else if (Orientation != 0) {
            //rotate to portrait
            Settings.System.putInt(context.getContentResolver(),
                    Settings.System.USER_ROTATION, 0);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
user_rotation 0 -> ROTATION_0
user_rotation 1 -> ROTATION_90
user_rotation 2 -> ROTATION_180
user_rotation 3 -> ROTATION_270
```

More information found here :
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.System.html#USER_ROTATION
Hope this helps :)

Comment: I rotated screen to lanscape in first time launch but cannot rotate it back